# How to merge a dictionary with two lists as the value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, tuples

I have a dictionary in this format:

```
{
    'a': ([1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]),
    'b': ([1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]),
    'z': ([],[-1])

}
```

And another one:

```
{
    'a': ([4,5],[]),
    'c': ([1,2,3],[-4]),
    'z': ([],[-3])
}
```

I would like to combine both of them into this format:

```
{
    'a': ([1,2,3,4,5],[-1,-2,-3]),
    'b': ([1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]),
    'c': ([1,2,3],[-4]),
    'z': ([],[-1,-3])
}
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm also fairly new to Python and I'm wondering if this would be the best way of representing my data and if there is some data structure I should be using instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Why did you ignore the empty `[]` in merging `a` but included when merging `z`?

Comment: In the first dictionary the second value of the tuple has [-1,-2,-3] so the resulting dictionary has the second list of key 'a' as [-1,-2,-3]

Comment: "some structure you should be using instead" to answer that fairly, its important to have some background about why you're doing these things, what these numbers mean, and so on.

Comment: One of the great things about Python are its in-built data structures like sets, lists, tuples and dictionaries. Right now you have, as far as I can tell, choosen the right data stuctures.

Comment: If you have `dict` value with tuple, you need to rethink about the structure of it as tuple are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
d1 = {'a': ([1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]),'b': ([1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]),'z': ([],[-1])}
d2 = {'a': ([4,5],[]),'c': ([1,2,3],[-4]),'z': ([],[-3])}
d3 = {}
d4 = {**d1, **d2}  # This will work for Python 3.5+
for k in d4:
    if k in d2 and k in d1:
        tm = (d1[k][0]+ d2[k][0], d1[k][1]+d2[k][1])
        d3[k] = tm
    elif k in d2 and k not in d1:
        d3[k] = d2[k]
    else:
        d3[k] = d1[k]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
d3 = {'a': ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [-1, -2, -3]), 'b': ([1, 2, 3], [-1, -2, -3]), 'z': ([], [-1, -3]), 'c': ([1, 2, 3], [-4])}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break this problem into two steps, using a helper function that handles the merging.

```
dict1 = {
    'a': ([1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]),
    'b': ([1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]),
    'z': ([],[-1])

}

dict2 = {
    'a': ([4,5],[]),
    'c': ([1,2,3],[-4]),
    'z': ([],[-3])
}

def ordered_list_merge(lst1, lst2):
     ''' 
     Merges two lists, and does not add duplicates from lst2 into lst1
     '''
    resulting_list = lst1.copy() #to ensure list 1 is not mutated by changes to resulting_list
    resulting_list.extend(x for x in lst2 if x not in resulting_list)
    return resulting_list

import copy
result_dict = copy.deepcopy(dict1) #to ensure result_dict is an entirely new object, and mutations on result_dict do not affect dict1

for k, v in dict2.items():
    if k not in result_dict:
        result_dict[k] = v
    else:
        result_dict[k] = tuple(ordered_list_merge(lst1, lst2)
                            for lst1, lst2 in 
                            zip(result_dict[k], v))
print(result_dict) 
#Output:
{'a': ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [-1, -2, -3]),
 'b': ([1, 2, 3], [-1, -2, -3]),
 'z': ([], [-1, -3]),
 'c': ([1, 2, 3], [-4])}
```

Note that dictionaries are inherently unordered (or remember insertion order in python 3.7+) and should not be relied on for order. Use a sort to get a list of tuples, or use an OrderedDict if the order is also important.